# Materializecss - scrollFire plugin seems not to be working

Tags: materialize

I don't have any idea why scrollfire plugin doesn't work
I use official guide http://materializecss.com/scrollfire.html

javascript is the following:

```
        var options = [

{selector: '.activator', offset: 500, callback: function() {
  Materialize.fadeInImage(".activator");
} }
  ];

 Materialize.scrollFire(options);
```

Here's my plunker demo: http://embed.plnkr.co/aA66og3NhkhafSHLQC5R/

Do you have any ideas why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm a total noob at programming so forgive me if I can't explain exactly why it's working this way. There were 3 things I changed to get it to work.

1. I changed the script tag to pull from an updated version, namely this one:  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js"
2. The offset has to be less than 500, I'm guessing its pixels, but from where the image is in the HTML its not firing unless I used a lower number. So I'm guessing either move the image up in the document or lower the offset.
3. Make sure when using the 'showStaggeredList()' or 'fadeInImage()' that you have the css for the element set to 'opacity: 0;'

I have it working so I'm hoping this will help you out.